# nullpointerexception for mongodb insert

Tags: java, mongodb

I have the following piece of code which is supposed to insert a document into a MongoDB Collection as shown below (Note I have the @Slf4j annotation above the class which should let me use log):

```
    public Document functionName(Document document) {

        return reactiveMongoTemplate.insert(document)
                .doOnSuccess(param -> log.info("Successfully saved"))
                .onErrorResume(e -> {
                    String message = format("Error saving %s", e.getMessage());
                    log.error(message, e);
                    throw new Exception(message, e);
                })
                .block();
    }
```

When I made a unit test case for this, and tested the function, I am getting a nullpointer exception on the line with doOnSuccess, when I really expect the test to pass. Is there something specific to the reactiveMongoTemplate that I'm missing here?

Here is the unit test:

```
    @Test
    void successfulMongoInsertion() {
        String xmlString = "<header>\n" +
                "    <to>Me</to>\n" +
                "    <from>You</from>\n" +
                "</header>";

        JSONObject json = XML.toJSONObject(xmlString);
        Document xmlDocument = Document.parse(json.toString());

        service.functionName(xmlDocument);
        ArgumentCaptor<Document> captor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(Document.class);
        verify(reactiveMongoTemplate).insert(captor.capture());

        Document retrievedDocument = captor.getValue();
        assertTrue(xmlDocument.equals(retrievedDocument));
    }
```

Service is the object that has the functionName method I included before.

Comment: Does your unit test set the value of `log` ?    Since the test is failing, could you paste the test code as well ?

Comment: done - it doesn't test the value of log, I thought log just outputs and wouldn't raise a nullpointer exception.

Answer (score 0):

Your unit test method doesn't instantiate log from your main class. You could make it assignable through a constructor or a java bean and pass a new logger before testing.

Comment: I have a @Slf4j annotation above the class which should allow me to use log - I have edited the question

Comment: can we be sure that the reactiveMongoTemplate is configured correctly?